# Use an array as a comparison in a WHERE query

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

I came upon a problem, I create arrays with variations of lengths. These arrays hold names, now I want to compare these names in a `WHERE` query.

Now I am thinking about a simple and nice solution, but I cant think of anything.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
array[?] names; //This is an array that holds names
sql Names = new SQLcommand("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name="the array names"",
                           _msConnection);
```

Hope you have a solution.

Comment: You want a logical `AND` or `OR` with your names?

Comment: Yep, but the problem is that I dont know how many times I need to place an AND or OR beqause the lengt of my array is different every time my function is executed..

Comment: @Akshinthalaసాయికళ్యాణ్, that's not so bad with an Integer array but with a String array you are open to SQL injection if the values are input by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL would be like this:

`WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')`

If you want to build that SQL the dodgy way then you might do it like this:

```
sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN ('{0}')", String.Join("', '", names))
```

If you want to see how to do it the proper way, [click here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?544951-Using-Parameters-with-an-SQL-IN-Clause).

Comment: I know, but the problem is that i don't know how many items my array holds. So I dont know have many values to place..

Comment: @thijs1095 try the code - it doesn't matter how many elements your array holds

Comment: @thijs1095 anyway you can use `List` instead of `Array`

Comment: This will work, but is not secure.

Comment: @Nayan, what's not secure?  Using string concatenation is open to exceptions and SQL injection and that's exactly why I said that that is the dodgy way. Here in Australia, "dodgy" means suspect.  The link I provided provides code that uses parameters and is therefore not susceptible to either of those issues, hence my describing it as the proper way.  Did you follow that link?

Comment: @Grundy, how does using a List over an array help?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list of values in array as a single column table. This is TVP. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Benefit: You can pass big arrays of same type and variable lengths and is more secure than string replacement and other hacks.

You create a type, first.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE (
      CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50))
```

Then use this type as argument to a function or SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_UpdateCategories (
    @tvpNewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY)
```

In C#, create object based on type:

```
SqlParameter tvpParam =
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", dataReader);
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.Replace()`

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name=$array$"
```

then

```
sql  = sql.Replace("$array$", array[index]);
```

Do the loops to for the array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say 'names' is an array or string You can make the use of String.Join() method
Which takes seperater and an array as Input and gives the string containing comma seperated items in array. Hope below is helpful.

```
var commaSeperatedNames = string.join(',',names);

var query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE name IN (" + commaSeperatedNames + ")";
```